# Postgresql create extension fails

Tags: postgresql

I'm using extensions and had no problems so far.
Now I create a new one, and  when I call 
create extension util; 
I get in PG 9.2:

$ create extension util;
FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei »﻿«
ZEILE 1: create extension util;

and in PG 9.1 :
CREATE EXTENSION util;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "﻿create"
LINE 1: CREATE EXTENSION util;

I have an util--1.0.sql , and even when this file is empty I get the error.
my util.control looks like this:

```
comment ='Hilfsfunktionen für Updateskripte'
default_version = '1.0'
schema=system
```

Any hints  ?
Rolf

Comment: Hrm. I do not get that error. You don't by chance have a `CREATE EXTENSION` statement in `util--1.0.sql`, do you?

Comment: No, the error also appears, when util--1.0.sql is an empty file !

Comment: Weird. Are both your server and your client actually 9.1 or 9.2? What's the output of `psql --version` and of `psql -c 'SELECT version()'`?

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure that the server you're connecting to is neither 9.1 nor 9.2. Connect to it and run `SELECT version();` to confirm.

Comment: Good guess. This was exactly my problem.