# Geodjango with PostgreSQL 8.4.20 and PostGIS 2.2

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to use Geodjango with a somewhat older version of PostgreSQL (8.4.20). When trying to migrate the model generated in python to the database (`python manage.py migrate`), it throws the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "EXTENSION"
LINE 1: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18220311/4139249), this probably has to do with the fact that I'm using an older version of PostgreSQL/PostGIS. But since I've already installed PostGIS, this command (`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis`) which attempted by django is not necessary. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hardly a surprise as the minimum version of Postgresql that is supported by Postgis 2.2 is posgresql 9.1

According to the [Version Compatibilit Matrix](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgreSQLPostGIS) the latest version of Postgis that you might be able to use with 8.4 is 2.00 but it's going to be a lot of hard work.